# blank values returns when using greater than operator in SQlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
select cars.car_id, cars.doors from cars where cars.doors>2
```

the previous query returns results greater than 2 in addition to empty values and 'N/A' , I tried NOT NULL but it doesn't make sense that blank is greater than 2

Comment: Can you provide your table and column structure?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: What is the datatype of `cars.doors`?

Comment: if you are asking about doors type it's INTEGER(5)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order) says:

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

To prevent empty entries from matching, you should change the database to use SQL's NULL value, not an (empty or non-empty) string.

Alternatively, convert your values that mean "empty" to an actual NULL value while querying:

```
where nullif(cars.doors, 'N/A') > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the implicit conversion, when you have the empty data, doing the comparison, it will be converted to 0.

```
select case when '' = 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

The result is 1.

Comment: but 0 is not greater than 2

Comment: you could add the `convert` into your select query to see what is the converted value

Comment: thanks for the hint i converted it to integer and worked

Comment: There is no implicit conversion. The result of this query is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
select doors from cars where cast(doors AS integer)>2;
```

it works as expected but i still don't get it why i should have converted it to integer although the field type is integer